# Why I can't import modules whose names include blank space in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I'm trying to import two modules that I have created before separately called "Program 5-26 circle.py" and "Program 5-27 rectangle.py". I failed in importing them at first. After I changed their names to be "circle.py" and "rectangle.py", I succeeded.

Is it that I cannot import modules whose name include blank space? Is there any specific rule in naming module other than not including blank space? What is the mechanism behind that or what is the motivation for the designer to design it in this way?

Comment: What is your motivation for including spaces in module names?

Comment: Well, I just started learning programming. It was a habit for me to keep spaces in naming files. I will try not including it in the future.

Comment: The *why* should be clear from looking at the error message, especially in more recent versions of Python.